# Allow space into my Regex

Tags: php, regex

I cannot find a way to allow a space in this regex for extract between title tag

```
 <title>my exemple</title>
```

here is the regex

```
 $pattern = "/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i";
```

I tried

```
 /<title>(.+)<\/title>/i\s
 /<title>(.+)<\/title>/i\S
 /<title>\s(.+)<\/title>/i
 /<title>(.+)\s<\/title>/i
```

here is the full fonction

```
function getSiteTitle(){
$RefURL = (is_null($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? 'Un know' : $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if($RefURL != 'Un know'){
$con = file_get_contents($RefURL) or die (" can't open URL referer ");
$pattern = "/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i";
preg_match($pattern,$con,$match);
$result = array($match[1],$RefURL);
return $result;
```

i have verified that i receive a keyword in my referer , because it work petty well with keywords without space

thx  you

Comment: Where is the space supposed to be?

Comment: a regular expression match for a space is, well, a space

Comment: Probably you need: `"/<title>(.+?)<\/title>/is"`

Comment: the space that need to be allowed are between the  title tag Kingkero

Comment: Isn't `.` matching spaces as well?

Comment: thx you anubhava , i tried your solution but does not work , there might need to do something between begin/end title tag but i dont know how to do this

Comment: @Maltazar Provide some example input so we know what you're trying to match. Don't reformat it, paste it exactly as it appears.

Comment: I guess all people here believe space = whitespace where your definition of space = linebreak?

Comment: @Maltazar: Try: `"/<title>(.+?)<\/title>/isu"`

Comment: the `(.+)` matches everything between the title tags INCLUDING spaces..  Not understanding why or how you should be having a problem.

Comment: @Maltazar edit your question with example inputs and outputs, and let us figure out the regex, it would be easier.

Comment: @Maltazar: Did you try: `"/<title>(.+?)<\/title>/isu"` Also provide snippet of `var_dump($con);`

Comment: i edited the question with the full fonction, im gonna try with /isu & let you know thx you all

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture HTML on multiple lines (is that what you mean by "spaces"?), you'll need to turn on the [`s` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), which allows the `.` character to match newline characters, as well.

This should work:

```
/<title>(.+)<\/title>/is
```

Comment: the title should contain a keyword , this work well as it with  keywords without space but make problem with space

Comment: SpikeX thx you but its the same as anubhava & it didnt worked

Comment: @Maltazar Provide the HTML of what you're trying to match, please.

Comment: it need to extract & allow everything between title tag                    <title>my exemple.pdf</title>

Comment: The expression that I (and others) have provided will do that - you're doing something else wrong. Can you please post the section of your code where you're executing this?

Comment: ok i like to copy the code but its pain to add it via comment...( i didnt get it) so here is the main part of the code http://pastebin.com/deUBrXVg (sorry)

Comment: i tried your code TWiStErRob (thx you) but didnt worked in my case

Comment: @Maltazar Did you verify that you had the contents of the URL? After getting the HTML but before the Regex call, check to make sure `$con` has vaild HTML data that you can even match on first.

Comment: SpikeX yes i verified that i get content because when i try with a keyword without space it give me correct output

Comment: @Maltazar You're doing something else wrong, or your HTML has some other characters that are not being accounted for. I just tried it with [this fiddle](http://ideone.com/80NGuW), and it works with and without spaces. The output clearly shows the captured title text with, and without spaces. You're just going to have to debug it by yourself, but the problem is *not* the regular expression.

Comment: ok i will report result thx you very much ,its amazing community !!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$pattern = "/<title>\s*(.+)\s*<\/title>/i";
```

then the first capturing group will contain only the keyword, which may contain spaces, like:

```
<title>      key  word    </title>
// result is "key  word"
```

add the `s` modifier to the end (`/.../is`) if you want to allow newlines inside title as well.

If I got what you want right, you could also use this approach:

```
$pattern = "/<title>(.+)<\/title>/is";
```

and then [trim](https://www.php.net/trim) the first capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting text between title text and the tags as well:

```
/<title>(.+)<\/title>/
```

Doing the same even if they are spread over multiple lines:

```
/<title>(.+)<\/title>/s
```

Doing the same as above but ignoring cases (lower or upper case doesn't matter)

```
/<title>(.+)<\/title>/is
```

Now we are using lookbehind and lookahead in order to only select the text between the tags:

```
/(?<=<title>)(.+)(?=<\/title>)/is
```

Please change the flags (i and s) the way you need them.

If that doesn't solve your problem I don't know what will :)

Here you can see an example of how my last regex would work: http://regexr.com?37ukf

EDIT:

Ok, try to test this code somehere:

```
<?php 
$title = '<title> My Example </title>';
preg_match('/(?<=<title>)(.+)(?=<\/title>)/is', $title, $match);
var_dump($match);
?>
```

You'll see that it works perfectly fine. Now with this knowledge go ahead and check if `$con` truly looks the way you think it should. And do a `var_dump` of your `$matches` instead of looking for specific indices.

Comment: thx you Layne , i tried all solution you listed but none worked in my case

Comment: Of course they do. Click on the link I provided and you'll see they do. My bet is your string inside $con is corrupted.

Comment: thx for the advice of var_dump to debug myslef Layne ,i have tested your snippet & it work as it but not with $con ,so you mean that there is a problem with the $cond but this parameter is working well without space actually so all solution proposed for my case do not work :(